# Openpyxl - Apply Borders to Cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am hoping someone can help me as I have been unable to figure this one out for myself unfortunately.

I am trying to put a thin border around a cell using openpyxl 2.3.3 and python 3.4. I have the following code:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Border

ws.cell('A1').border = Border(top = Side(border_style='thin', color='FF000000'),    
                              right = Side(border_style='thin', color='FF000000'), 
                              bottom = Side(border_style='thin', color='FF000000'),
                              left = Side(border_style='thin', color='FF000000'))
```

Oddly this is throwing the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Side' is not defined
```

I have looked at the official documentation here:

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.4/styles.html
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.4/_modules/openpyxl/styles/borders.html

I have also looked at the following articles with no luck:

https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/365/styling-merged-cells-isnt-working

[Applying borders to a cell in OpenPyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917201/applying-borders-to-a-cell-in-openpyxl)

[Apply borders to all cells in a range with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650059/apply-borders-to-all-cells-in-a-range-with-openpyxl)

[Apply Border To Range Of Cells Using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520764/apply-border-to-range-of-cells-using-openpyxl)

Is anyone able to help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Eamon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't imported the `Side` object.

`from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side`

Comment: Doh! So simple. Thank goodness you were around. Thank you Charlie :-)